# Unable to locate nested p element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

How would I locate the "tile" element in the HTML:

```
<div class="con-head">
  <div class="up-at js-con-dates">
    <span class="bold">Last date</span>
    7:13 PM <br>
    <span class="bold">Save</span>
    7:12 PM
  </div>
  <p class="tile">Text: Kids </p>
  <p class="desc js-desc" style="">Q&A </p>
</div>
```

I tried to locate it with the accessor:

```
div(:my_title) { div_element(:class => 'con-head').div_element(:class => 'tile') }
```

But it is not working and giving the error:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:class=>"tile", :tag_name=>"div"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML, the element with class "tile" is actually a `p` element:

```
<p class="tile">Text: Kids </p>
```

As a result, you need to locate it using the `paragraph_element` method instead of the `div_element` method:

```
div(:my_title) { div_element(:class => 'con-head').paragraph_element(:class => 'tile') }
```